# Access function arguments from another function

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I am trying to create a custom debug tool and I need to use a component with two separate functions in it. The first function (`startTimer`) has some arguments such as `startCount` and the other one (`endTimer`) has `endCount`. What I am trying to accomplish is something like the following code:

```
<cffunction name="startTimer" access="public" returntype="void">
    <cfargument name="startActionTime" type="string" required="no">
</cffunction>

<cffunction name="endTimer" returntype="void" access="public">
    <cfargument name="endActionTime" type="string" required="no">

    <cfset finalTime = endActionTime - startTimer.startActionTime>

    <!---Some SQL will go here to record the data in a db table --->

</cffunction>
```

And this is how I am calling the function

```
<cfscript>
    location = CreateObject("component","timer");

    loc =location.startTimer(
        startActionTime = getTickCount()
    );


    end = location.endTimer(
        endActionTime = getTickCount()
    );


</cfscript>
```

I guess I am having scope issues because when I am trying to run the code I am getting an undefined error on `startTimer.startActionTime`. What is the correct way to do something like this?

Comment: Your functions are not returning anything. The first, startTimer, is not even doing anything?

Comment: well ideally I would want the first function to only capture a running time and then use that value on the endTimer. I see what you are saying and I think I can do this with only 1 function instead. Just over thought the whole thing I guess

Comment: What is the use case for this?  If you trying to time the execution of cfc methods by wrapping this around them, then using AOP to wrap the target in a proxy would be a much better solution.

Comment: I want to create a function that captures different running times such as queries, view rendering time and so on. When we get error emails from CF for certain sites I would like to enable this code and start recording data for debugging

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `variables` scope like so:

```
<cfcomponent>

  <cfset variables.startActionTime = 0>

  <cffunction name="startTimer" access="public" returntype="void">
    <cfargument name="startActionTime" type="numeric" required="no">

    <cfset variables.startActionTime = arguments.startActionTime>
  </cffunction>

  <cffunction name="endTimer" returntype="string" access="public">
    <cfargument name="endActionTime" type="numeric" required="no">

    <cfset finalTime = endActionTime - variables.startActionTime>

    <!---Some SQL will go here to record the data in a db table --->
    <Cfreturn finaltime>

  </cffunction>

</cfcomponent>
```

From the Adobe Docs: Variables scope variables created in a CFC are available only to the component and its functions, and not to the page that instantiates the component or calls its functions.

Comment: Those variables will still only be accessible to the function in which they are defined.

Comment: Only var'd variables will be restricted to use within the function itself. http://www.dougboude.com/blog/1/2006/06/ColdFusion-Component-Variable-Scopes-This-Variables-and-Var.cfm

Comment: Notice in your reference that he is using the `variables` scope outside of the `<function>` tags. That is what makes it accessible to all of the functions within that component. Not by using the scope itself.

Comment: the Adobe docs for CF8 say: The Variables scope in a CFC is private to the CFC. It includes variables defined in the CFC body (initialization or constructor code) and in the CFC methods. This still holds true in CF10 and I presume CF9, as well. It is best practices to param the variables outside the functions, but it's not required.

Comment: The CF9 doc link to this topic: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7dfb.html

Comment: It works just fine. Even though I have to re-think my process and do it with only one function instead of two.

Comment: I see that you updated your answer by initializing the `variables.startActionTime` variable outside of the `<function>` tags...

Comment: I did that for you buddy. Though it's not required, I think it's best as an example of best practices.

Comment: Well it does indeed work in ColdFusion 9 without initializing the variable within the constructor or initialization code. I could have sworn that I had tried that before and it did not work. I will give you an up-vote for answering the original question and for enlightening me.